Apache embedded tomcat integration with multiple proxy load balancer
I am trying to configure one Apache server with multiple  application those running tomcat server using proxy balancers with different port numbers. I am using spring boot embedded tomcat server. Posting the configuration below,  am using (-DjvmRoute=jvm2) in order to change the JVM for each application respectively. Could you please help me where I am doing wrong?
### Enable LoadModule entry for Apache mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http ###
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
 
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy balancer://myset>
    BalancerMember hostname:7001 route=jvm1
    ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
    ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
</Proxy>
<Proxy balancer://viewer>
    BalancerMember http://hostname:7002 route=jvm2
    ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
    ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
</Proxy>
<Proxy balancer://prsreg>
    BalancerMember http://hostname:7003 route=jvm3
    ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
    ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /  balancer://myset/
ProxyPass /app1/  balancer://myset/
ProxyPass /app2/  balancer://viewer/

ProxyPass /ap3/  balancer://prsreg/
 

<Location /app1>
  Require all granted
  
</Location>
<Location /app2>
  Require all granted
</Location>

<Location /app3>
  Require all granted
</Location>

</IfModule>

Could you please guide on the Apache configuration with multiple proxy load balancers?

using the latest apache version 2.4.61 and with Amazon Linux 2

Can somebody help on this
